# ERROR lua/test.lua:4: attempt to call field 'PlayFile' (a nil value)

Tags: lua, garrys-mod

```
local AudioSource = nil

hook.Add("EntityTakeDamage", "UniqueNameForYourScript", function()
    sound.Play("sound/hurt1.mp3", "", function(source, err, errname)
        if IsValid(source) then
            AudioSource = source
            source:Play()
        else
            print("Error playing sound: " .. errname)
        end
    end)

    print("OW!")
end)
```

thats the script i used for glua and it says

> "[ERROR] lua/test.lua:4: attempt to call field 'PlayFile' (a nil
> value)"

When i try to run it

i tried to run it. it didnt work

Comment: are you actually using `sound.Play` or `sound.PlayFile` as you seem to be mixing up the syntax. `sound.PlayFile( string path, string flags, function callback )` vs `sound.Play( string Name, Vector Pos, number Level, number Pitch, number Volume )`

Comment: Confusingly the code has the correct arguments (types at least) for [`sound.PlayFile`](https://wiki.facepunch.com/gmod/sound.PlayFile), the error indicates `sound.PlayFile` is *nil*, but the matching line in the code shown calls [`sound.Play`](https://wiki.facepunch.com/gmod/sound.Play) (with the wrong arguments). You will need to clarify this question further. Please confirm you are posting the problematic code, after confirming that you are testing the intended code (make sure you are saving files before attempting to utilize them, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

It would be good to know, how you run the script.

I will assume that you are running it via the console command lua_openscript, which executes a script serverside. Its important to notice that [sound.PlayFile](https://wiki.facepunch.com/gmod/sound.PlayFile) is not available on the serverside. You either need to network this to the client or change your code to not use that function.

In addition to that, your code is missing some key options like a Vector for the position at the second argument.